# Space-filling ToolBar item in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I make an item inside a `ToolBar` fill all the remaining available space? Or, how to right-align some items, since that would give me the same effect in my case.

Note that solutions which involve nesting another container (like a `Grid`) inside the `ToolBar` don't work since that disables the special behaviour `ToolBar` gives to it's items (like no normal borders and look, simple outline border on hover, not receiving focus after click, etc.).

Additionally, anyone knows how to get rid of the little button that would show additional icons that overflowed from the toolbar if I had any?

Comment: Is this not the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232386 ? If so, how did you miss that when asking this one? It's the VERY FIRST suggestion when typing in your question!

Comment: Sorry, I saw that question, but the suggestions involve the the "container nesting" approach, which has the problem I described in my question. Since I wasn't sure if I shoul've "bumped" that question I decided to post a new one.

Comment: Ok no problem. Now that these comments are here clarifying that it's not a dupe, nobody will close this one.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using this solution:

http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2008/01/23/wpf-sample-series-stretch-toolbar-width-of-window/

It's not ideal, but it works. I still don't know how to get rid of the dropdown on the end though.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the button at the end by re-templating the toolbar. You can likely solve your other query this way too.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote up a soluton for creating a "space filling" label that dynamically sizes to allow to you "right-align" items in a toolbar.  Check it out: [WPF Toolbar Items HorizontalAligment="Right"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201685/wpf-toolbar-items-horizontalaligment-right/6006516#6006516)