# C# WPF Make a toolbar align right within a toolbartray

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, toolbar

I have three WPF Toolbars in a ToolBarTray and I want two of them to be on the left and one of them to float on the right.

```
<ToolBarTray DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <ToolBar>
            <ComboBox/>
        </ToolBar>
        <ToolBar>
            <Button/>
            <Button/>
            <Button/>
        </ToolBar>
        <ToolBar HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Button/>
            <Button/>
            <Button/>
        </ToolBar>
</ToolBarTray>
```

I have messed around with trying to set the margin programatically on the rightmost toolbar but it feels hacky. At runtime it is possible to move the toolbars around in the tray so it just feels like I am missing something obvious.

Maybe I should be using different controls?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I helped

Code is from Mark Cidade answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/21293250/4597322):

```
<ToolBar VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <ToolBar.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolBarPanel}">
            <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical"/>
        </Style>
    </ToolBar.Resources>

    <DockPanel>
        <ToolBarPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <Button>A</Button>
            <Button>B</Button>
        </ToolBarPanel>
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right">C</Button>
    </DockPanel>
</ToolBar>
```

Comment: I think I saw this answer, my issue is that I am actually using some custom user controls that derive from ToolBar and I want to put them all in one bar (tray) and lay them out.