# Alignment items in toolbar left corner and righ corner in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2015

with Custom tool window I tried with align buttons in a dock panel  horizontal left and right it works fine, but i want the same thing do with the toolbar, but it could not work.

And also it dock with Visual studio left and right side and toolbar should overflaw the content (Visual studio default behavior) 
[This is my current implementation with dockpanel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DmO5.png)
My code is this,

```
Xaml
```

```
        <Button Background="Gray" Content="btn1"></Button>
        <Button Background="Red" Content="btn2" ></Button>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Button Background="Gray" Content="btn1"></Button>
            <Button Background="Red" Content="btn2" ></Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF Toolbar Items HorizontalAligment="Right"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201685/wpf-toolbar-items-horizontalaligment-right)

Comment: unfortunately Microsoft decided that all toolbars are now left aligned only you have to override the default style to change this

Comment: Hi @MikeT can u please give me a sample?

Comment: see the link on my first comment