# How can I create a full-width toolbar with the buttons centered in WPF app?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, toolbar

I have an WPF app written in c#. I need to create a toolbar with a full-width background where the toolbar button in the middle.

Here is my `XAML` code

```
<ToolBarPanel ToolBarTray.IsLocked="True"
              Style="{StaticResource ContentRoot}">

    <ToolBar VerticalAlignment="Center"
             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
             Loaded="ToolBar_Loaded"
             MinWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ToolBarTray}}, Path=ActualWidth}">

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Command="{Binding StepBackward}"
                    ToolTipService.ToolTip="Go to previous page"
                    ToolTipService.Placement="Mouse"
                    Height="32">

                <fa:FontAwesome Icon="StepBackward"
                                FontSize="18" />
            </Button>

            <Button VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Command="{Binding Backward}"
                    ToolTipService.ToolTip="Go to first page"
                    ToolTipService.Placement="Mouse"
                    Height="32">

                <fa:FontAwesome Icon="Backward"
                                FontSize="18" />
            </Button>

            <TextBox Text="{Binding PageNumber}"
                     Width="50"
                     TextAlignment="Center"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     Padding="0, 4"
                     IsReadOnly="True"
                     ToolTipService.ToolTip="Current selected page"
                     ToolTipService.Placement="Mouse"
                     Height="32" />

            <Label Content="{Binding OfPageCount}"
                   Padding="5"
                   Height="32" />

            <Button VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Command="{Binding Forward}"
                    ToolTipService.ToolTip="Go to last page"
                    ToolTipService.Placement="Mouse"
                    Height="32">

                <fa:FontAwesome Icon="Forward"
                                FontSize="18" />
            </Button>

            <Button VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Command="{Binding StepForward}"
                    ToolTipService.ToolTip="Go to next page"
                    ToolTipService.Placement="Mouse"
                    Height="32">

                <fa:FontAwesome Icon="StepForward"
                                FontSize="18" />
            </Button>

            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PageSizes}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPageSize, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      DisplayMemberPath="Text"
                      SelectedValuePath="Value"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                      Width="75"
                      Padding="0, 5"
                      ToolTipService.ToolTip="Show selected amount of records per page"
                      ToolTipService.Placement="Mouse"
                      Height="32" />



            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Pages}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPage, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      DisplayMemberPath="Text"
                      SelectedValuePath="Value"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                      Width="75"
                      Padding="0, 5"
                      ToolTipService.ToolTip="Go to selected page"
                      ToolTipService.Placement="Mouse"
                      Height="32" />


            <Label Content="{Binding OfItemCount}"
                   Padding="5"
                   Height="32" />

        </StackPanel>
    </ToolBar>
</ToolBarPanel>
```

My code show the buttons in the center as expended but the background "ToolBarPanel" does not stretch all the way across my screen as desired.

How can I stretch the background on my ToolBar?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution from [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201685/wpf-toolbar-items-horizontalaligment-right)

```
     <!-- ... -->
     <ToolBar VerticalAlignment="Center"
         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
         MinWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ToolBarTray}}, Path=ActualWidth}">

            <ToolBar.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DockPanel}">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </ToolBar.Resources>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
     <!-- ... -->
```

To make it work, I had to change the `HorizontalAlignment` of your `ToolBar` and set it to `Stretch` and add the `DockPanel` style override.

Why changing `DockPanel` style if you're not even using one? The [default WPF ToolBar style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/toolbar-styles-and-templates) uses one, so our code is overriding this inner `DockPanel` to make sure our content is centered. Note that this style override will be applied to all `DockPanel` inside your `ToolBar` children, for now you don't use any but if you add one someday, you'll either want to explicitly set its `HorizontalAlignment` to `Left` or remove the `DockPanel` style override and create your own `ToolBar` style (inspired from the default style) with a `DockPanel` `HorizontalAlignment` set to `Center`.

Comment: The ugliest thing because of the ugliest decision of XAML architects. 10 years (from 1995) everyone was afraid of JavaScript. Now JavaScript solutions to all such problems is like an ice cream in a hot weather or a gulp of brandy in a cold weather.